# yii url manager

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to match this URL:

```
http://www.example.org/en/site/page/id/1
```

with these rules:

```
'rules'=>array(
      '/'=>'site/index',      
      '<lang>/<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index', 
      '<lang>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',      
      '<lang>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>/<id>',   
      '<lang>'=>'/',   
),
```

I think it's valid but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url contains an "id" string/text http://www.example.org/en/site/page/id/1 which is not required...

Try url with

```
http://www.example.org/en/site/page/1
```

Or append one more route as

```
'<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/id/<id:\d+>' =>'<controller>/<action>/<id>',
```

It should work both ways..

Comment: Thanks for the hint in your answer !`'<lang:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/id/<id:\d+>' =>'<controller>/<action>/id/<id>'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the language parameter routing is not in the correct format. Try this:

```
'rules' => array(
  '/'                                                     =>'site/index',      
  '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>'                       =>'<controller>/index', 
  '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'          =>'<controller>/<action>',      
  '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' =>'<controller>/<action>/<id>',   
  '<language:\w+>'                                        =>'/',   
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the more specific rules to the top.

```
'rules'=>array(
      '<lang:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>/<id>',                  
      '<lang:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',      
      '<lang:\w+>/<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index', 
      '<lang:\w+>'=>'/',   
      '/'=>'site/index',      
),
```

[edit] fixed lang regex *credits to Moz Morris.